# How to prevent JsonStringEnumConverter from throwing an error if the conversion failed in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some enum which represents discount types:

```
public enum DiscountType
{
  TypeA,
  TypeB,
}
```

There's a class called Discount which contains a property of type DiscountType

```
public class Discount
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public DiscountType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize a message using such a call:

```
var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Discount>(fooBar);
```

When "fooBar" message contains invalid value in a section corresponding to DiscontType the deserialization fails with the following message:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The JSON value could not be converted to xxx.DiscountType. Path: $.yyy.type | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 726.) ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to xxx.DiscountType.
```

Is there a way to assign some specific value to DiscountType property on such a failure? Is there any other way than creating a custom converter? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Inherit from `JsonStringEnumConverter` and override that behaviour.

Comment: @DavidG This class is sealed :/

Comment: Then the answer is probably "no, create a custom converter". You can still delegate to the existing class for the values it is prepared to handle (use aggregation rather than inheritance).

Comment: Then make your own from the original https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2ebd621c81d0c1ef1c6950d2b08a54487b6f0125/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonStringEnumConverter.cs